# Prevent checking checkbox input in contentEditable from stealing focus from editor in Android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, checkbox, webview, focus

Unfortunately `event.preventDefault` inside of `mousedown` doesn't do the trick. I tried the same inside of `pointerdown` (no luck) and `touchstart` (it says the event is not cancellable)

I can't insert any additional, invisible elements to intercept the event instead of the checkbox receiving it. Do I have any options for this or am I out of luck?